# find matches for multiple words

Tags: java

I have this PostgreSQL table for storing words:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('processed_words_id_seq'::regclass),
    keyword character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
);

insert into words (keyword)
VALUES ('while swam is interesting', 
        'ibm is a company like bmw');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trademarks
(
   id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('trademarks_id_seq'::regclass),
   trademark character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
);

insert into words (trademarks)
VALUES ('while swam', 
        'ibm',
        'bmw');
```

Into table `trademarks` I will have thousands of registered trademarks names.
I want to compare words stored into `words` table keyword, do they match not only for a words but also for word which is in a group of words. For example:

I have a keyword `while swam is interesting` stored into `words.keyword`. I also have a trademark `swam` located in `trademarks.trademark` like `ibm` I have a word match, so I want to detect this using Java code.

First I want to select all blacklisted keywords convert them in for example List and compare `ibm is a company like bmw` with elements from the list. How I can do this not only for one word but also for a expressions?

something like this?

```
Optional<ProcessedWords> keywords = processedWordsService.findRandomKeywordWhereTrademarkBlacklistedIsEmpty();

        if(keywords.isPresent())
        {
            List<BlacklistedWords> blacklistedWords = blacklistedWordsService.findAll();
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for(BlacklistedWords item:  blacklistedWords){
                list.add(item.getKeyword());
            }

            ProcessedWords processedWords = keywords.get();
            String keyword = processedWords.getKeyword();

            if(list.contains(keyword))
            {
                System.out.println("Found blacklisted word in keyword: " + keyword);
            }

        }


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "trademarks")
public class BlacklistedWords implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "trademark", length = 200, unique = true)
    private String keyword;
}
```

Can you guide me how this can be implemented?

Comment: What is `BlacklistedWords` class? And why do you need it?

Comment: this is the entity (table trademarks)

Comment: This looks very much like an [X-Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): What is it you're *actually* trying to do (without reference to tables or classes)? Please give several examples of data and what the desired outcome is.

Comment: If you want a solution using `BlacklistedWords` you must show the code for that class. Also, how many rows are in each of the 2 tables?

Comment: Thanks for showing the class. Please also provide the row counts for each table.

Comment: words - 30 million, trademarks - 340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do the matching with Java streams:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // stubbing up the persistence layer
    List<BlacklistedWords> blacklistedWords = Arrays.asList(new BlacklistedWords[] {new BlacklistedWords(1, "while swam"), new BlacklistedWords(2, "ibm"), new BlacklistedWords(3, "bmw")});
    List<ProcessedWords> keyWords = Arrays.asList(new ProcessedWords[] {new ProcessedWords(1, "while swam is interesting"), new ProcessedWords(2, "ibm is a company like bmw"), new ProcessedWords(3, "miss")});
    

    
    List<ProcessedWords> hits = keyWords.stream()
              .filter(pw -> blacklistedWords.stream()                    
                  .anyMatch(bw ->                                 
                       pw.getKeyword().indexOf(bw.getTrademark()) != -1))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    System.out.println(hits);

}
```

Output:

```
[ProcessedWords(id=1, keyword=while swam is interesting), ProcessedWords(id=2, keyword=ibm is a company like bmw)]
```

Note that I stubbed out the persistence layer with an additional `ProcessedWords` of "missed" and annotated `BlacklistedWords(table=trademarks)` & `ProcessedWords(table=words)` with `@Data` to get a decent `toString()`, which you shouldn't because they are `@Entity`.

Comment: I checked the code but the thing is that I need to find a match for whole words.

Comment: Although the problem suggests it, I would avoid a regex. Replace pw.getKeyword().indexOf(bw.getTrademark()) != -1 with { final String trademark = bw.getTrademark(); final String keyword = pw.getKeyword(); return keyword.contains(“ “ + trademark + “ “) || keyword.startsWith(trademark + “ “) || keyword.endsWith(“ “ + trademark) || keyword.equals(trademark);}

Comment: I have added another answer to  satisfy the requirement for whole words.

Answer (score 1):

In order to satisfy the requirement for whole words, the following should be done.

```
    List<BlacklistedWords> blacklistedWords = Arrays.asList(new BlacklistedWords[] {new BlacklistedWords(1, "while swam"), new BlacklistedWords(2, "ibm"), new BlacklistedWords(3, "bmw")});
    List<ProcessedWords> keyWords = Arrays.asList(new ProcessedWords[] {new ProcessedWords(1, "while swam is interesting"), new ProcessedWords(2, "ibm is a company like bmw"), new ProcessedWords(3, "miss")});
    
    Set<ProcessedWords> hits = new HashSet<>();
    blacklistedWords.parallelStream().forEach(bw -> {
        final String trademark = bw.getTrademark();
        final String startsWith = trademark + " ";
        final String contains = " " + startsWith;
        final String endsWith = " " + trademark;
        keyWords.parallelStream().forEach(pw -> {
            final String keyword = pw.getKeyword();
            if (keyword.contains(contains) || keyword.startsWith(startsWith) || keyword.endsWith(endsWith)
                    || keyword.equals(trademark))
                hits.add(pw);
        });
    });
```

Because the output we require is a subset of keyWords and we do not want to recalculate the " " + trademark + " ", etc in the inner stream, the following is not advised, but works:

```
    List<ProcessedWords> hits1 = keyWords.parallelStream().filter(pw -> blacklistedWords.parallelStream().anyMatch(bw -> {
        final String keyword = pw.getKeyword();
        final String trademark = bw.getTrademark();
        return keyword.contains(" " + trademark + " ") || keyword.startsWith(trademark + " ") || keyword.endsWith(" " + trademark) || keyword.equals(trademark);
    })).collect(Collectors.toList());
```